# How to make the Interface (or type) Properties start with a specific character?

Tags: typescript

I tried to solve this task with template literals, but failed.

I've got some interface:

```js
interface SomeInterface {
    '@prop1': string;
    '@prop2': string;
    '@propN': string;
}
```

Is there a way to make this work without adding properties manually?
I need all properties to start with the "at" sign.

Comment: do you have already existing interfaces that you need to dynamically transform or do you just want to define you interface

Comment: @DivisionByZero I want to define my own interface from scratch

Comment: Since you only need to define your interface once, just write out all properties.  If you are looking for something to enforce this consistent naming, this is literally what the interface is for. Sorry, but your question doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: My question has a big sense! I've just simplified it. I believe it's not important to know about my final purpose. I need to make the `TypeScript` compiler complain when I do NOT put the "@" sing at the beginning of the prop name. That's it. Is it possible or not?

Comment: No that is not possible. You are asking the typescript compiler to know what your interfaces will look like. What you are looking for is a linter for consistent code writing rules. [Have a look at eslints naming-convention-rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md)

Comment: @DivisionByZero you said it's not possible, but it's possible and I knew it! See my answer to this question!

Comment: Clearly, you don't understand the difference between defining an interface and instantiating an object that satisfies a specific interface. That's why I was asking if you need the defined interface (what you answered yes with) or if you need a guard to convert your keys (what your answer describes). You given answer does not answer the question you have given. You should probably read the guide about ["How to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
const asSomeInterface = <K extends PropertyKey>(obj: { [P in K]: P extends `@${string}` ? string : never }) => obj;

asSomeInterface({
    '@asd': 'asd',
    'asd': 'asd', // error
});
```